# Flutter MediaQuery of() method - understanding the definition

Tags: flutter

Below is the Flutter definition for MediaQuery.of(),

```
MediaQueryData of (
BuildContext context
)
```

> The data from the closest instance of this class that encloses the
> given context.

Here what is the ,

1. closest instance ?
2. "this" class means which class?
3. Would be much helpful if someone can provide me with a pictorial
   representation of closest instance in terms of widget tree?

Answer (score 0):

1. Closest instance means that you go up the tree from the current widget (where you call `MediaQuery.of`) and the first `MediaQuery` you encounter is the one you're looking for.
2. This class here means the `MediaQuery` class.
3. Something like this:

```
Widget1
 - MediaQuery – not in the same sub-tree
 - MediaQuery - not the closest one
   - Widget2
   - MediaQuery - the closest one, the data from it will be returned
     - Widget3
       - YourWidget (you call MediaQuery.of here)
```